# Why does a mapped println only work when last in a let block?

Tags: clojure

Why does

```
(defn tester []
  (let [bar #{"a" "b" "c"}]
    (+ 1 1)
    (map println bar)))
```

print

```
a
b
c
```

to an emacs cider repl, but not

```
(defn tester []
  (let [bar #{"a" "b" "c"}]
    (map println bar)
    (+ 1 1)))
```

Comment: Thank you Alan and Sean! This is great. I never like having to choose which answer is the most helpful with the checkmark on this site when multiple answers are equally helpful. :-)

Answer (score 5):

`map` is lazy and if you do not use (realize) the whole value, it will avoid doing unnecessary work.

In a `let` (and also in a function and in a `do`), the value of the last expression is the value of the whole form. The other forms are evaluated and their results thrown away: so `(map println bar)` is evaluated -- to produce a lazy sequence -- but then that lazy sequence is thrown away without realizing the values in it.

If you want `map`-like behavior for a side-effecting function (such as `println`), you can use `run!`: `(run! println bar)` -- this will eagerly consume the sequence `bar` and apply `println` to every element.

Note: if you use `mapv` which is eager instead of lazy, you'll get a vector full of `nil` values -- the result of each call to `println` -- so you almost certainly do not want to do that.

You could also use `doseq` but it's more verbose than `run!`:

```clj
(doseq [item bar]
  (println item))
```

Comment: ```run!``` is a new one for me... awesome.

Answer (score 2):

The `map` function is meant to transform each value in a sequence into another value.
It is also a "lazy" function that doesn't normally execute until the output values are needed.  For these reasons `map` is not the best choice for printing data.

For your purposes you should use the `doseq` function for imperative processing.  You could also use the `mapv` function which is not lazy, and just ignore its output (note that `println` always returns `nil` - not very useful).

Please see [this list of documentation resources](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template#documentation). The Clojure CheatSheet is especially valuable.

Comment: Ah, I had forgotten about ```doseq``` here, vs map.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `doall` to force the side-effects in the lazy sequence produced by `map`:

```
(defn tester []
  (let [bar #{"a" "b" "c"}]
    (doall (map println bar))
    (+ 1 1)))
```

prints

```
a
b
c
2
```